# Can't change the css properties of jQuery UI dialog titlebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I can't change the background color of jQuery UI dialog titlebar. I am coding like this:

```
jQuery("#divId").dialog({
            title: 'Information'
});
jQuery("#divId .ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background-color", "red");
```

By the way, my application will open only in IE. I tried to detect titlebar and footer css properties with IE developer tools, but it won't detect titlebar and footer. But it recognizes css properties of ui-dialog-content. Please suggest me.

Comment: You mean there's no title in your UI dialog?

Comment: title exists.. but doesn't allow me to change style?

Answer (score 3):

titlebar is a sibling of the div dialog so try:

```
jQuery("#dialog").prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css("background", "red");
```

Just specifying the background-color is not sufficient instead you need to override the background which is put in place by the following rule on the title div which places a background image.

```
.ui-widget-header {
   border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorHeader}*/;
   background: #cccccc/*{bgColorHeader}*/ url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlHeader}*/ 50%/*{bgHeaderXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgHeaderYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHeaderRepeat}*/;
   color: #222222/*{fcHeader}*/;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

But it will be a much better idea to use css styling. Specify a `dialogClass` for this particular dialog which you want to customize.

```
jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
    title: 'Information',
    dialogClass: 'info'
});
```

and provide a rule for that and make sure your stylesheet is loaded after jquery ui's.

```
.info .ui-widget-header {
    background:red;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVEqr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the class is better than all of that.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'custom-dialog',
    create: function () {
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').removeClass('ui-widget-header');
    }
});
```

And style like you would with your new '.custom-dialog' class